# Use ExpandProperty to select a single property from an object

Tags: powershell

when I do something like:

```
Get-Objects | Where ($_.prop1 -ne $null} | select -ExpandProperty prop1
```

It returns all objects where prop1 aren't null. What if I want to get all objects where subprop = "10" , for example get all objects where prop1.subprop = 10, and select that value?

Do we have something like `Get-Objects | where { $_.prop1/subprop -eq "10"} | select -ExpandProperty prop1/subprop?`

I am not sure how to make it work like this

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a note from [About Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7#equality-operators):

> If you need to compare a value to `$null` you should put `$null` on the
>   left-hand side of the comparison. When you compare `$null` to an
>   Object[] the result is False because the comparison object is an
>   array. When you compare an array to `$null`, the comparison filters out
>   any $null values stored in the array.

PowerShell has two nice features:

1. [Member enumeration](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/new-v3-language-features/) (PowerShell v3+)
2. The equality operators (`-eq`, `-ne`) return a value of TRUE [***or the matches***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7#equality-operators) when one or more of the input values is identical to the specified pattern.

This means if you just looking for **the values** of the sub-properties, the syntax is as simple as this:

### `(Get-Objects).prop1.subprop -eq 10`

**Example:**

```
Function Get-Objects {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Prop1 = [pscustomobject]@{SubProp1a = 10; SubProp1b = 11}
        Prop2 = [pscustomobject]@{SubProp2a = 20; SubProp2b = 11}
    },
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Prop1 = [pscustomobject]@{SubProp1a = 20; SubProp1b = 22}
        Prop2 = [pscustomobject]@{SubProp2a = 10; SubProp2b = 22}
    },
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Prop1 = [pscustomobject]@{SubProp1a = 10; SubProp1b = 33}
        Prop2 = [pscustomobject]@{SubProp2a = 20; SubProp2b = 33}
    }
}

(Get-Objects).Prop1.SubProp1a -eq 10
10
10
(Get-Objects).Prop1.SubProp1b -gt 20
22
33
```

Comment: Well this is much better than the rubbish I wrote earlier. +1

Comment: @RoadRunner, thanks for the credits, I think I have to make a note about `Set-StrictMode -Version 2` which will cause an error if either the property or the sub-property misses. From the question I suspect could be the case. But I need to further think the trough as I suspect that this is actually a general disadvantage of member enumeration...